# Lumia 640 screen brightness

Tags: lumia-640

Can the screen brightness be increased somehow on the Lumia 640 to be more visible in sunlight. The screen setting is already set to bright.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to Setting >> System >> Display
- Disable automatically adjust display brightness

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions however they have already been initiated without sucess. Has anybody with a Lumia 640 actually been able to read the screen in bright sunlight/daylight and if so how have you achieved this result?